# git filter does not run

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to implement [this](http://timstaley.co.uk/posts/making-git-and-jupyter-notebooks-play-nice/) solution, which implies creating a filter in git. I added these filters in .git/config

```
[core]
attributesfile = .gitattributes

[filter "nbstrip_full_test"]
    clean = "echo Hello World .git/config"
    smudge = cat

[filter "nbstrip_full"]
clean = "jq --indent 1 \
        '(.cells[] | select(has(\"outputs\")) | .outputs) = []  \
        | (.cells[] | select(has(\"execution_count\")) | .execution_count) = null  \
        | .metadata = {\"language_info\": {\"name\": \"python\", \"pygments_lexer\": \"ipython3\"}} \
        | .cells[].metadata = {} \
        '"
smudge = cat
required = true
```

and this in .gitattributes

```
*.ipynb filter=nbstrip_full_test
*.ipynb filter=nbstrip_full
```

However, when I commit or run `git checkout jupyter/exploration.ipynb`, I don't see the filter being applied. What's wrong?

Find the setup in [this](https://github.com/frederikho/git-issue) test repo.

```
git version 2.39.2
```

Comment: The checked-out file is only rewritten if there *is* something to check out. Did you `rm jupyter/exploration.ipynb` before the `checkout` command?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. However, this doesn't solve the issue. I also expect the output "Hello world" in the console which doesn't happen.

Comment: Does the file contain `Hello World .git/config`? If not, use `GIT_TRACE=1` to see if the commands are actually executed.

Comment: No, the file doesn't contain that. But I as I understand the documentation (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#filters_b) it doesn't need to. 
After `rm jupyter/exploration.ipynb` and `GIT_TRACE=1 git checkout jupyter/exploration.ipynb` I get this:
`09:33:26.662103 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git checkout jupyter/exploration.ipynb
09:33:26.665392 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: cat
Updated 1 path from the index`

Comment: So, there you have it. The smudge filter (`cat`) did run. The clean filter runs when you `git add` the file. (I got these two wrong in my earlier comments as well. Sigh.)

Comment: Oh yeah, right. That makes sense and solves my main problem. Thanks! If you convert your comments to an answer I can accept it as the solution. Do you also know why the test filter does not run the echo command? I get this: `GIT_TRACE=1 git add jupyter/exploration.ipynb 
17:05:39.549434 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git add jupyter/exploration.ipynb
17:05:39.550916 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: 'echo Hello World .git/config` (if I remove the other filter)

Comment: Use `git show :jupyter/exploration.ipynb` (note the colon; this shows the contents of the staged file). You will see that the content is `Hello World .git/config`. At least, it should. It did for me in my tests. The content of the working tree file remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the *clean* and *smudge* filters run, set the environment variable `GIT_TRACE=1`. The output includes the filter commands that are invoked (see examples in the comments).

Note also that commands that look at working tree files, such as `git add` and `git diff` run the *clean* filters. Commands that copy data from the repository to the working tree, such as `git checkout`, run the *smudge* filters.